# Facebook API - Post as page in community groups

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

With the new feature of connecting pages with groups (https://grytics.com/blog/link-facebook-groups-pages/) I tought, that it would be possible to post as page on group feed via Graph API. All my tries ended up with errors saying:

> there´s no Edge/Node 'groups' on page

```
require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client;
use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => '123456',
    'app_secret' => 'abcde',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    //'default_access_token' => PAGE_TOKEN, // optional
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
$permissions = ['user_managed_groups', 'publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'publish_pages'];

$tokenFileName = "./fb-token.txt";
$date = new DateTime();
$cityToPost = 'Berlin';
$autopostGroups = array();
$message = array(
    'message' => 'TEST Post: '.$date->getTimestamp(),
    'link' => 'https://domain.de'
);

try {
    // Refresh longlicedaccesstoken with new one
    if (file_exists($tokenFileName)) {
        $token = file_get_contents($tokenFileName);
        $lastTokenRefresh = time() - filemtime($tokenFileName);
        if ($lastTokenRefresh > 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
        {
            $oAuth2Client  = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
            $newToken      = $oAuth2Client->getAccessTokenFromCode(
                $oAuth2Client->getCodeFromLongLivedAccessToken(
                    $token
                )
            );
            file_put_contents($tokenFileName, (string) $newToken);
            $accessToken                       = (string) $newToken;
        }else{
            $accessToken                       = (string) $token;
        }
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    unlink($tokenFileName);
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    unlink($tokenFileName);
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (file_exists($tokenFileName)) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken(file_get_contents($tokenFileName));
    } else {
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken((string) $accessToken);
        file_put_contents($tokenFileName, (string) $longLivedAccessToken);
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);
    }
    // redirect user back to app when page receives $_GET['code'] variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='https://apps.facebook.com/xyz/';</script>";
        exit;
    }

    // validating the access token
    try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unlink($tokenFileName);
            //unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/xyz/', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    // get list of groups managed by user
    try {
        $requestGroups = $fb->get('/me/groups');
        $groups = $requestGroups->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        if(strpos($group['name'], 'VENDOR') !== false && strpos($group['name'], $cityToPost) !== false){
            array_push($autopostGroups,$group['id']); //Only for debugging

            try {
                $requestPost = $fb->post('/'.$group['id'].'/feed', $message);
                $post = $requestPost->getGraphNode()->asArray();

                var_dump($post);
            } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }

    }
    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $tokenFileName
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/xyz/', $permissions);
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
```

I am new to the fb api, and I am not a english native speaker, so maybe someone is able to clearify that situation?

Thank you!

**[EDIT 1]**

Added code. Hint: When I change `PAGE_TOKEN` to `USER_TOKEN` it works.

**[EDIT 2]**

Full Code added.
I found a user comment in the FB Group [Facebook Developer Community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1498895813487261/?comment_id=1499055233471319&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R5%22%7D) from August:

> And no, there is no build-in way to have page posts show up in a group
>   automatically.

Comment: Please provide the code you used to generate that error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @neuromatter sorry, you´re right!

Comment: You are not trying to access a `groups` node on a page id in the code as shown so far - so that error likely occurs earlier already. Btw., a script that tries to indiscriminately post into every group associated with an account that it can find, rather smells like spam.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thanks for your response! Earlier in the code I only get access_token for a user. Even if I manual do this and use a page access_token, there is no possibility to access connected groups with page and post in it. Is this possible over the API at all? I Never found a solution for this.

Trust me, this is not spam. It is a script for a sinlge vendor platform. It always post only to one group with schema like VENDOR-CITY.

Comment: _“Earlier in the code I only get access_token for a user”_ - no, you must be doing more - for example filling the `$groups` variable you loop over ...

Comment: @CBroe Added full code. You are right, I get a full list of groups from a user. Seems there is no other endpoint for this. I also added a comment ..... **oh haha... now I see, that comment is from you :D...** 
So is it true, that it is not possible to add posts as page to a group via api, yet?